# How to glance at items and make them glow gradually and individually? (Unity3d c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose maximum brightness of an item is 100% and vice versa. When I glance at one of them, the item should be gradually brightening up from 0% to 100%. So when I look away halfway of the brightening, the object will slowly dim back to 0%. When I glance back again, the brightening will just resume. I am using Color.Lerp for my brightening and dimming back down.

Each item has their own individual pace of brightening and dimming back down even when they are gathered in a very tight space.

Assume that Item A, B, C, D and E arranged tightly beside each other in order. Hence, I glance at Item A which its brightness has reached to 80% and I immediately shift through B,C and D then stop and glance at E to reach its maximum brightness. In this scenario, A should be dimming back down, while B, C and D brightens up a little bit. Then E will be brightening to the max. How do I achieve this no matter how many items I have on the spot? I am having problem with updating the info of current item and keeping the info of previous item.

The code works well on a single item AND ALSO glancing back and forth between two items. But when there are three or more objects involved, the codes just doesn't work anymore.

Scripts are as below:

1. Raycast to detect items

```
public class RaycastSelection : MonoBehaviour
{

    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray ray;

    public GameObject currentObject;
    public GameObject previousObject;
    public GameObject lastPreviousObject;
    public GameObject lastObject;

    private bool saveObjectOnce = false;
    private bool isFading = false;
    private bool fadeOnce = false;

    private ColorFade colorFading;
    private ColorFade colorFading1;
    private ColorFade colorFading2;

    public void Start()
    {
        colorFading = GameObject.FindWithTag("Puzzle").GetComponent<ColorFade>();
        colorFading1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Clue").GetComponent<ColorFade>();
        colorFading2 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Selectable").GetComponent<ColorFade>();

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        Vector3 forward = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, forward, Color.red);

        //if player is looking
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            var selection = hit.transform;
            if (selection.CompareTag("Puzzle") || selection.CompareTag("Clue") || selection.CompareTag("Selectable"))
            {
                //if it is first time looking at object
                if(currentObject == null)
                {
                    currentObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                }
                //if it is second time looking at object
                else
                {
                    if (saveObjectOnce == false)
                    {
                        previousObject = currentObject;
                        saveObjectOnce = true;
                    }
                    currentObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                }

                //if previous and current object are same
                if(string.Equals(currentObject, previousObject))
                {
                        isFading = true;

                        ColorFade fadingColor = currentObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                        fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);

                    if (lastPreviousObject != null)
                    {
                        isFading = false;
                        ColorFade fadingcolor = lastPreviousObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                        fadingcolor.FadeCheck(isFading);
                    }

                }
                //if previous and current object are different
                else
                {
                    lastPreviousObject = previousObject;
                    previousObject = currentObject;
                }
            }
            //if detects other objects than the items
            else
            {
                lastObject = currentObject;

                isFading = false;

                if (lastObject != null)
                {
                    ColorFade fadingColor = lastObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                    fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);
                }


            }
        }
        //if the player is not looking 
        else
        {
            lastObject = currentObject;
            if (lastObject != null)
            {
                ColorFade fadingColor = lastObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

2. Changing brightness of the item (This script is attached to each item individually)

```
public class ColorFade : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private bool saveColorOnce = false;
    [SerializeField] private Transform thisObject;

    [SerializeField] private Color startColor;
    [SerializeField] private Color EndColor;

    [SerializeField] private float lerpFadeTime = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        startColor = this.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        thisObject = this.transform;
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void FadeCheck(bool fadingStatus)
    {
        if(fadingStatus == true)
        {
            FadeIn();
        }
        else
        {
            FadeOut();
        }

    }

    private void FadeIn()
    { 
            Debug.Log(this.transform.gameObject.name);
            Debug.Log("FadeIn");

            lerpFadeTime += Time.deltaTime / 3f;

            thisObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, EndColor, lerpFadeTime);

            if(lerpFadeTime >= 1f)
            {
                lerpFadeTime = 1f;
            }
    }

    private void FadeOut()
    {
            Debug.Log(this.transform.gameObject.name);
            Debug.Log("FadeOut");

            lerpFadeTime -= Time.deltaTime / 3f;

            thisObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, EndColor, lerpFadeTime);

            if (lerpFadeTime <= 0f)
            {
                lerpFadeTime = 0f;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You lost me, "I glance at Item A which its brightness has reached to 80% and I immediately shift through B,C and D then stop and glance at E to reach its maximum brightness. In this scenario, A should be dimming back down, while B, C and D brightens up a little bit. Then E will be brightening to the max." why would B, C and D be brightening a if your not "Glancing" at them when you state "When I glance at one of them, the item should be gradually brightening up from 0% to 100%. So when I look away halfway of the brightening, the object will slowly dim back to 0%."

Comment: You aren't tracking "all previously looked at items" only the most recent. As soon as your glance changes to C, A will no longer dim because you're dimming B.

Comment: This video shows similar thing, but with different effect https://youtu.be/cxJnvEpwQHc

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks a ton! I do make a huge mistake when storing the objects that raycast had previously hit. I made some changes and the code works fine now.

Comment: @SagiZiv Thanks for the reference! I will check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which are most of the times better to control than using complex `Update` methods with timers, states and bools.

```
public class RaycastSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components")]

    // reference this via the Inspector already if possible
    [SerializeField] private Camera camera;

    [Header("Debug")]

    [SerializeField] private ColorFade lastFaderHit;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!camera) camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
        {
            // if hitting same object do nothing
            if (lastFaderHit && hit.transform == lastFaderHit.transform) return;

            // if looking on different object start fade out previous if exists
            lastFaderHit?.FadeOut();

            // start fade in current
            var current = hit.transform.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
            current?.FadeIn();

            // update previous hit
            lastFaderHit = current;
        }
        else
        {
            // if looking at nothing start fadeout previous hit if exists
            lastFaderHit?.FadeOut();

            // reset previous hit
            lastFaderHit = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and in `ColorFade` use coroutines like

```
public class ColorFade : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components")]
    // reference this in the Inspector if possible
    [SerializeField] private Renderer renderer;

    [Header("Settings")]

    [SerializeField] private Color startColor;
    [SerializeField] private Color EndColor;

    // fade duration for a complete 0-100 fade
    // fading will be shorter if only fading parts
    [SerializeField] private float fadeDuration = 1f;

    [Header("Debug")]

    [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 1f)] private float currentFade;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        startColor = renderer.material.color;
    }

    public void FadeIn()
    {
        // avoid concurrent routines
        StopAllCoroutines();

        StartCoroutine(FadeTowards(1));
    }

    public void FadeOut()
    {
        // avoid concurrent routines
        StopAllCoroutines();

        StartCoroutine(FadeTowards(0));
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeTowards(float targetFade)
    {
        while (!Mathf.Approximately(currentFade, targetFade))
        {
            // increase or decrease the currentFade according to the fade speed
            if (currentFade < targetFade)
                currentFade += Time.deltaTime / fadeDuration;
            else
                currentFade -= Time.deltaTime / fadeDuration;

            // if you like you could even add some ease-in and ease-out here
            //var lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, currentFade);

            renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, EndColor, currentFade /*or lerpFactor for eased fading*/);

            // let this frame be rendered and continue from this point
            // in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I was thinking of using array class to store all the items that player has glanced at, then remove them once it has done fade out. But came to think of that method could be very expensive to use it. 

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

## Fade an object out if it's not currently being viewed

Don't worry about which objects are fading out and not selected. That is the job of the fader. If it's not being viewed, it's fading out. It's that simple.

---

### Fader.cs - Put this component on your objects that can be faded

```
public class Fader : MonoBehaiour
{
    // Flag to know if the object is currently being viewed
    public bool IsCurrentlyViewed = false;

    // Time in seconds it takes to fade from 100% brightness to 0% brightness. Default is 3 seconds
    [SerializeField] private float SecondsTimeToFade = 3.0f;

    // Ratio from 0 to 1 to indicate how bright an object should be
    [SerializeField] private float PercentRatioBright = 0.0f;

    // Start and end colors 
    [SerializeField] private Color startingColor;
    [SerializeField] private Color endingColor;

    // Cache the renderer
    private Renderer renderer;

    public void Start()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        startingColor = renderer.material.color;

        if (layer < 8)
            Debug.LogWarning("Fader layer should be set to a player-defined layer");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Fade in when being viewed, fade out when not
        if (PercentRatioBright > 0.0f && PercentRatioBright <= 1.0f)
            Fade();
        
        // Reset the IsCurrentlyViewed bool
        IsCurrentlyViewed = false;
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        float brightnessRatioUnsignedDifference = Time.deltaTime / SecondsTimeToFade;

        PercentRatioBright += brightnessRatioUnsignedDifference * (IsCurrentlyViewed ? 1 : -1);

        renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startingColor, endingColor, PercentRatioBright);
    }
}
```

### Example call:

```
public class ThroughTheLookingClass : MonoBehaiour
{
    // Set this so you only hit what you want with the ray
    // Make sure your selectable objects have this layer
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask SelectableLayerMask;

    public Update()
    {
        // Cast screen point to ray, select objects with layermask and have the Fader component
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition, out RaycastHit hit, layerMask: SelectableLayerMask)))
        {
            hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Fader>()?.IsCurrentlyViewed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! it is enlightening to know there is other way to write the codes. Thank you for the help! Appreciated!

Comment: In the example call, you can improve the efficiency in 2 main ways: 1) don't use camera.main in update, store the value in global variable.  
2) You can create another script that holds all the instances of Fade.cs and then get them from there instead of GetComponent

Answer (score 0):

I revisit my own script and made some changes, so the code works out fine now.

RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray;

```
public GameObject nextObject;
public GameObject currentObject;
public GameObject previousObject;


public GameObject lastPreviousObject;
public GameObject lastObject;

private bool saveObjectOnce = false;
private bool isFading = false;
private bool fadeOnce = false;

public void Start()
{

}

public void Update()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector3 forward = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
    Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, forward, Color.red);

    //if player is looking
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        var selection = hit.transform;
        if (selection.CompareTag("Puzzle") || selection.CompareTag("Clue") || selection.CompareTag("Selectable"))
        {
            nextObject = selection.gameObject;
            //if previous and current object are same
            if (GameObject.Equals(nextObject, currentObject))
            {
                    isFading = true;

                    ColorFade fadingColor = currentObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                    fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);


                if(previousObject != null)
                {
                    isFading = false;
                    ColorFade fadingcolor1 = previousObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                    fadingcolor1.FadeCheck(isFading);
                }

                if(GameObject.Equals(currentObject, lastPreviousObject))
                {
                    lastPreviousObject = null;
                }
                else {
                    if (lastPreviousObject != null)
                    {
                        isFading = false;
                        ColorFade fadingcolor = lastPreviousObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                        fadingcolor.FadeCheck(isFading);
                    }
                }




            }
            //if previous and current object are different
            else
            {
                lastPreviousObject = previousObject;
                previousObject = currentObject;
                currentObject = nextObject;
            }
        }
        //if detects other objects than the items
        else
        {
            isFading = false;
            lastObject = nextObject;
            if (lastObject != null)
            {
                ColorFade fadingColor = lastObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
                fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);
            }
        }
    }
    //if the player is not looking 
    else
    {
        isFading = false;
        lastObject = nextObject;
        if (lastObject != null)
        {
            ColorFade fadingColor = lastObject.GetComponent<ColorFade>();
            fadingColor.FadeCheck(isFading);
        }

    }
```